# How to extract and join files xxx.zip, xxx.z01 and xxx.z02

Tags: files, extract, join

I have these three files: `1.zip`, `1.z01` and `1.z02`. I would like to extract and join them into a single file, by right clicking `1.zip` and selecting *Extract Here*. But then there comes an error:

```
7-Zip 9.04 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-05-30
p7zip Version 9.04 (locale=en_US.utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)

Error: /home/tim/Desktop/1.zip:
Can not open file as archive

Errors: 1
```

I was wondering what the problem is and how I can solve it?

---

**ADDED:**

Is my usage of `unzip -FF` wrong? It seems not working:

```
$ unzip -FF 1.zip 
Archive:  1.zip
warning [1.zip]:  zipfile claims to be last disk of a multi-part archive;
  attempting to process anyway, assuming all parts have been concatenated
  together in order.  Expect "errors" and warnings...true multi-part support
  doesn't exist yet (coming soon).
file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  0
```

**2nd ADDED:**

Still ain't right:

```
$ cat 1.z01 1.z02 1.zip > combined.zip && unzip -FF combined.zip
Archive:  combined.zip
warning [combined.zip]:  zipfile claims to be last disk of a multi-part archive;
  attempting to process anyway, assuming all parts have been concatenated
  together in order.  Expect "errors" and warnings...true multi-part support
  doesn't exist yet (coming soon).
warning [combined.zip]:  209829313 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  209829313
  (attempting to re-compensate)
 extracting: 1.wmv   bad CRC ee181eef  (should be f3c61875)
```

It generated `1.wmv`, which can play well only until  midway in GNOME MPlayer.

**3rd ADDED:**

Am I using `7z` wrongly?

```
$ 7z e 1.z01

7-Zip 9.04 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-05-30
p7zip Version 9.04 (locale=en_US.utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)

Processing archive: 1.z01

Error: Can not open file as archive

$ 7z e 1.zip

7-Zip 9.04 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-05-30 
p7zip Version 9.04 (locale=en_US.utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)

Processing archive: 1.zip

Error: Can not open file as archive
```

Comment: Supplemental advice -- use "file x.z01" to possibly get critical information about the relevant compression algorithm. For instance, the zip utility wouldn't work on my multi-part zip, but once I checked the file info I saw "at least PKZIP v2.50 to extract" output, which led me to the proper algorithm and associated utility (unarchiver).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have the same issue today with Mass Effect 3. Someone broke the installation of Mass Effect 3 in new version of origin on windows and my wine of course too (installation hangs on 99%). I have to make manually installation:

```
cp /mnt/cdrom1/Mass\ Effect\ 3.z01 ~/temp/Mass\ Effect\ 3.z01
cp /mnt/cdrom2/Mass\ Effect\ 3.zip ~/temp/Mass\ Effect\ 3.zip
zip -FF Mass\ Effect\ 3.zip --out Mass\ Effect\ 3.zip.fixed
mkdir Mass\ Effect\ 3
unzip -d Mass\ Effect\ 3/ Mass\ Effect\ 3.zip.fixed
du --total Mass\ Effect\ 3
>> 10466048 (~10.5 GB => success)
```

`zip -FF` should be applied to last part of archive, it will automatically check for all parts

Answer (score 40):

Try:

```
zip -FF 1.zip --out 1-full.zip
unzip -FF 1-full.zip
```

I think most likely some data is broken many times so you need the `-FF` still in `unzip`. A single `-F` may work also though.

Comment: How to do this on Windows?

Comment: do we need -FF for unzip?

Answer (score 22):

Put all your zip files  in the same directory: ***zip_file.z01, zip_file.z02, zip_file.z03, ..., zip_file.zip***

In Zip 3.0 version the following commands worked for me:

```
$ zip -s- zip_file.zip -O zip_file_full.zip
$ unzip zip_file_full.zip
```

As noted in the comments, using a `-` sign after the command line option `-s` joins all the zip files together and writes it as a single zip file which you can then extract using the `unzip` command.

Answer (score 4):

I also had some issues. man unzip said the following:

> Also, zip 3.0 and later can combine multi-part (split) archives into a combined single-file archive using ``zip -s- inarchive -O outarchive''.

This (zip -s- vmdkdisk -O combined) seems to work for me... (combine vmdkdisk.z01 and vmdkdisk.zip into one file combined.zip)

Answer (score 1):

According to reading [`man zip`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/unzip.1.html), "**Split .zip**" archives can be recombined and unpacked using `unzip -FF`.

Comment: Thanks! But it seems not working. See my update to my post. Thanks!

Comment: `cat 1.z01 1.z02 1.zip > combined.zip && unzip -FF combined.zip` ?

Comment: Thanks! It now generates 1.wmv, but there is some error.

Comment: Does running `7z` (7-Zip) on the first `.z01` file work?

Comment: Still no. "Error: Can not open file as archive". See my update.

Answer (score 1):

Above solution by kmario23 is correct I see some typo errors. Here is another example.

```
    pramodimac:SDK pramod$ pwd
    /Users/pramod/Downloads/SDK
    pramodimac:SDK pramod$ ls -ltrh
    total 150104
    -rw-r--r--@ 1 pramod  staff   1.3M Jun  3 11:56 SDK.zip
    -rw-r--r--@ 1 pramod  staff    18M Jun  3 11:58 SDK.z03
    -rw-r--r--@ 1 pramod  staff    18M Jun  3 11:58 SDK.z04
    -rw-r--r--@ 1 pramod  staff    18M Jun  3 11:58 SDK.z01
    -rw-r--r--@ 1 pramod  staff    18M Jun  3 11:58 SDK.z02
    pramodimac:SDK pramod$ zip -s 0 SDK.zip --out single.zip
    pramodimac:SDK pramod$ ls -ltrh
    total 300208
    -rw-r--r--@ 1 pramod  staff   1.3M Jun  3 11:56 SDK.zip
    -rw-r--r--@ 1 pramod  staff    18M Jun  3 11:58 SDK.z03
    -rw-r--r--@ 1 pramod  staff    18M Jun  3 11:58 SDK.z04
    -rw-r--r--@ 1 pramod  staff    18M Jun  3 11:58 SDK.z01
    -rw-r--r--@ 1 pramod  staff    18M Jun  3 11:58 SDK.z02
    -rw-r--r--  1 pramod  staff    73M Jun  6 22:26 single.zip
    pramodimac:SDK pramod$ unzip single.zip
```

Comment: You might just edit his answer...

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory where the archives are, through terminal.

If they are on desktop, command is:

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

`~` is your home folder name. Create full archive, by using this command:

```
zip -F (name of last part of archive, which will end with .zip, not .z0X) --out (desired output name of compiled archive, if has spaces put " marks around the name).zip
```

Full archive is now created.
Unpack the full archive, by using this command:

```
unzip (full archive name, with " marks around it if has spaces).zip -d (destination folder directory, see first step)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears 7zip doesn't support `multi-volume ZIP` archives.

[Igor Pavlov states it in this forum thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/ecd56c62#e467)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if your follow up files (01, 02 etc.. ) are created by Windows (Z01, Z02 etc..) your linux will not find them. You need to rename the files to z01, z02 ..